# File sharing between MAC, Linux

Tags: linux, mac-osx, network-share, file-sharing

Here is what I want to do:
Share files between MAC OSX (snow leopard) machine and Ubuntu (10.* and 11.*) on a local network. I know 2 solutions:

Samba: easy to setup but it is not case sensitive so it does not work for me because I program Android stuff and it requires a case sensitive filesystem.

NFS: It works to transfer a few files but if you try to copy a large number of files it gets very slow and end up locking up. I tried to fix NFS with many solutions found on the WEB but none worked. Since I use some very nice Github Client (Tower) it just not work because it needs to deal with lots of file at the same time at it has the same behavior as a large number of file copy, it locks up after a few minutes.

What other solutions are available to share files between MAC and Linux (Ubuntu) with case sensitivity on a local network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I feel that samba is a great choice, I'm going to have to correct your statement.  The default setting for Samba is to rely on the OS to determine if they care about case sensitivity (`case sensitive = auto`).  For Linux and OSX, this defaults to `yes` (case sensitive), while windows defaults to `no` (case insensitive).  This is known as `name-mangling`, but wouldn't be an issue in your case.  [See the man page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) for details.

Its also important to note that Windows XP and beyond [have a better understanding of case sensitivity](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch05_04.html).

Comment: I agree with you on the beauty of the simplicity of Samba. I'm going to try that.

Comment: I finally got to do it. And thanks very much. it works great The only thing that makes it look like it's not OK is the fact that "finder" would display the wrong "case" for two file with the same name in the same folder except for the case (case.txt and Case.Txt would display identical like case.Txt). But if you look in a terminal, you can see it's OK.  So I can use my Mac-OSX git-tower to manage the Android files on a Linux Box.

Answer (score 1):

How about FTP/SFTP/SCP?

Comment: Do those allow the sort of "browsing" functionality I think he's looking for?

Comment: certainly you can browse directories yes

Comment: xmodem. You forgot xmodem.